# How to display custom <Errormessage> in formik field component and disable the default message

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I am making a web project using [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Material](https://next.material-ui.com/), [Formik](https://formik.org/), [formik-material-ui](https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui).

I have made a Formik form using [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) for validation.

```
const schema = yup.object({
    name: yup.string().trim().lowercase().required("Name is required."),
});

<Formik
    initialValues={{
    name: "",
    }}
    validationSchema={schema}
>
    {({ submitForm, isSubmitting, handleSubmit, handleChange, values }) => (
        <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Grid container direction="row" spacing={2}>
                <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={4}>
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                        <InputLabel>Patient Name *</InputLabel>
                        <TextField fullWidth name="name" type="text" />
                        <InputLabel>Patient ID: P0006</InputLabel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

The TextField is a custom component as follows

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import { TextField } from "libs/formik-material-ui/src";

const TextFieldStyle = {
    padding: 8,
    fontSize: "0.75rem",
};

export default React.memo((props: any) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Field
                component={TextField}
                inputProps={{
                    style: TextFieldStyle,
                }}
                size="small"
                margin="none"
                variant="outlined"
                {...props} // add props at the key to override any user defined similar props
            >
                {props.children}
            </Field>
            <ErrorMessage name={props.name}>{(msg) => <div style={{ color: "red", textAlign: "left" }}>{msg}</div>}</ErrorMessage>
        </Fragment>
    );
});
```

Since I want to display ErrorMessage of a different style and not the default one, I have added  below the field.
But with this approach, the error message is being printed twice.

[image]

How can I disable the default message from being printed ?

Comment: Please check the documentation [link](https://formik.org/docs/api/errormessage)

Answer (score 2):

### **You would need to remove your `{msg}` and let formik handle the error message for you**

And if you want to style the error, use className from formik:

**Formik Props Type**

```
export interface ErrorMessageProps {
    name: string;
    className?: string;
    component?: string | React.ComponentType;
    children?: ((errorMessage: string) => React.ReactNode);
    render?: ((errorMessage: string) => React.ReactNode);
}
```

**So you would need to use it like so**

```
<ErrorMessage name={props.name} className="your-class" />;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `helperText=""` to disabled default message

```
<Field
  component={TextField}
  inputProps={{
    style: TextFieldStyle,
  }}
  size="small"
  margin="none"
  variant="outlined"
  helperText=""
  {...props} // add props at the key to override any user defined similar props
>
```